# how to Write the arrays to a csv file in php?

Tags: php

I have a csv file with contents like this :

```
123  , 2021-08-07  , Tr  , Tam , Tr  , Tam
123  , 2021-08-07  , Tr  , Tem
1233  , 2021-08-07  , Ter  , Tdm
12333  , 2021-08-07  , Tor  , Tfem , Tr  , Tam
12333  , 2021-08-07  , Pr  , Tsem
123334  , 2021-08-07  , Tkr  , Tm , Tr  , Tam , Tsr  , TK-S
1233344  , 2021-08-07  , Thr  , TK , Tr  , Tam
12333445  , 2021-08-07  , Tsr  , TK-S
```

here I am reading the contents to the array and if an array has a certain value with the  array length of 4 then replacing the contents of that array :

```
$file = fopen('a.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  if($line[0] == "12333445")
  {
      $cnt= count($line);
      if ($cnt==4)
      {
        $line=array("0"=>"purple","1"=>"orange");  
      }
  }
  print_r($line); 
}
fclose($file);
```

This is the result of the `print_r($file);`

```
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Tr [3] => Tam [4] => Tr [5] => Tam ) 
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Tr [3] => Tem ) 
Array ( [0] => 1233 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Ter [3] => Tdm ) 
Array ( [0] => 12333 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Tor [3] => Tfem [4] => Tr [5] => Tam ) 
Array ( [0] => 12333 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Pr [3] => Tsem ) 
Array ( [0] => 123334 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Tkr [3] => Tm [4] => Tr [5] => Tam [6] => Tsr [7] => TK-S ) 
Array ( [0] => 1233344 [1] => 2021-08-07 [2] => Thr [3] => TK [4] => Tr [5] => Tam ) 
Array ( [0] => purple [1] => orange )
```

Now i want to write all of those arrays into the csv file to have something like this :

```
123  , 2021-08-07  , Tr  , Tam , Tr  , Tam
123  , 2021-08-07  , Tr  , Tem
1233  , 2021-08-07  , Ter  , Tdm
12333  , 2021-08-07  , Tor  , Tfem , Tr  , Tam
12333  , 2021-08-07  , Pr  , Tsem
123334  , 2021-08-07  , Tkr  , Tm , Tr  , Tam , Tsr  , TK-S
1233344  , 2021-08-07  , Thr  , TK , Tr  , Tam
purple , orange
```

How can i Achieve that ?

Comment: What's wrong with fputcsv?

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily edit data in the middle of a sequential file like CSV since the data you want to insert is almost certainly not the same size as the data you're removing.

The solution is to read the input file, write the new data to a new, temporary, file, then delete the old file and rename the temporary file to the original name.

For example:

```
<?php
$fileName = 'a.csv';
$tempName = 'temp.csv';
$inFile = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$outFile =  fopen($tempName,'w');
while (($line = fgetcsv($inFile)) !== FALSE) {
    if(($line[0] == "12333445") && (count($line) == 4))
    {
        $line=array("0"=>"purple","1"=>"orange");
    }
    print_r($line);
    fputcsv($outFile, $line );
}
fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
unlink($fileName);
rename($tempName, $fileName);
```

Note that this line-by-line read-and-write style is likely to deliver poor performance. For large files you'd do better to buffer input and output.

The example below uses `file()` to read the entire CSV file into memory and uses `str_getcsv()` to unpack it line by line before applying the updates and writing the result to a new file.

```
$fileName = 'a.csv';
$tempName = 'temp.csv';

$inData = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$outFile =  fopen($tempName,'w');

foreach($inData as $line) {
    $data = str_getcsv($line);
    if(($data[0] == "12333445") && (count($data) == 4)) {
        $data=["purple","orange"];
    }
    print_r($data);
    echo "\n";
    fputcsv($outFile, $data );
}
fclose($outFile);
unlink($fileName);
rename($tempName, $fileName);
```